# Number of subgroups of order $p^k$ in $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian $p$-group and $p^k\ge p^3$ be a proper divisor of $|G|$.

It is well known that the number of subgroups of order $p^k$ in $G$ is $1\pmod{p}$.

Divide the subgroups of order $p^k$ into two parts: abelian and non-abelian; which of them are $1\pmod{p}$ in number? Or is it possible that none of them are $1\pmod{p}$ in number? (Just stating the result is fine; I will try to prove it.)

Comment: It is possible for either of them to be equal to $1$ mod $p$, but I have not found any example in which neither of them is.

Comment: There's a lot of stuff on subgroup congruences in Berkovich's and Janko's "Groups of prime power order, Vol. I".